# Infinite loop in haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, ghci

I thought this would produce a factorial function...

(within ghci)

```
Prelude> let ft 0 = 1
Prelude> let ft n = n * ft (n - 1)
Prelude> ft 5
```

(hangs indefinitely, until ^C).

Answer (score 32):

The two separate `let` statements are interpreted independently from each other. First a function `ft 0 = 1` is defined, and then a new function `ft n = n * ft (n - 1)` is defined, overwriting the first definition.

To define one function with two cases you have to put both cases into a single `let` statement. To do this in a single line at the GHCI prompt you can separate the two cases by `;`:

```
Prelude> let ft 0 = 1; ft n = n * ft (n - 1)
Prelude> ft 5
120
```

Comment: In other words, what you wrote is (almost) correct Haskell; the problem is that GHCI accepts different syntax from what you'd put in a separate source file.  If you put those two lines, but without the word `let` (that's the "almost"), in a file Factorial.hs, then in GHCI enter:

`:load Factorial`

then

`ft 5`

you'll get 120.

Don't know if you've come across "do notation" yet (e.g. for I/O), but the syntax that's allowed at the GHCI prompt is the same as what's allowed inside a do block.