# Indentation errors in GHCi, implementing filter

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> let filter' p (x:xs) | p x = x : filter' p xs | otherwise = filter' p xs
Prelude> let filter' _ [] = []
Prelude> filter' odd [1..10]
*** Exception: <interactive>:1:5-21: Non-exhaustive patterns in function filter'
```

what pattern am i missing?

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let filter' p (x:xs)
Prelude|     | p x              = x : filter' p xs
Prelude|     | otherwise        = filter' p xs
Prelude| let filter' _ []       = []
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:2:5: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

what's the idiomatic way to define this (syntax wise) in ghci? what's up with lining up the `=` - i don't know how many spaces to leave for the below clauses before i define them! whats with the :{}:, is there a nicer way?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2901360/56338

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, using multiple `let` statements is making two separate definitions with the latter shadowing the former. Second, the reason for the syntax error is that you didn't indent your guards enough (the `| px ...` line should be indented further than `filter' p (x:xs)`).

Although it's simpler to keep your definitions in a file, here's how you'd enter it correctly in GHCi.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let filter' p (x:xs)
Prelude|      | p x       = x : filter' p xs
Prelude|      | otherwise = filter' p xs
Prelude|     filter' _ [] = []
Prelude| :}
```

The `:{` and `:}` commands are used to input a definition spanning multiple lines. Aligning the `=` is optional, it's the indentation of the lines that matters.

Answer (score 4):

Don't write your functions at the ghci prompt - save them in `MyFunctions.hs` or something and do

```
:l MyFunctions
```

in ghci.

The `let` command in ghci obliterates previous definitions, so when you do

```
let filter' p (x:xs) | p x = x : filter' p xs | otherwise = filter' p xs
let filter' _ [] = []
```

You're actually doing `let filter' p (x:xs) | p x = x : filter' p xs | otherwise = filter' p xs` then completely removing that definition to replace it with `let filter' _ [] = []`.

The `Non-exhaustive patterns` means you used the second definition of filter' on [1..10] which is not empty, and your second version of filter' only covers empty lists!

Your definitions are fine and work well, with no indentation errors, although `filter'' p (x:xs) | p x = x : filter' p xs | otherwise = filter' p xs` is ugly. I realise you were trying to write a one-liner in ghci, but text editor + ghci + http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ is a powerful combination!

Comment: and after that, `:r` to reload.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Andrew's answer, consider the following ghci session.

```
Prelude> let x = 1
Prelude> let x = 2
Prelude> x
2
```

That is, the `let` expression in ghci introduces a new variable and shadows the old definition. As Andrew suggested, simply save your definition to a file.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, each time you have a new `let` statement in GHCi, it overwrites the previous definitions. However, you can still use pattern matching by putting the definition into one `let` statement. There are essentially 2 ways of doing this.

Firstly, just use semicolons:

```
let filter' p [] = []; filter' p (x:xs) | p x = x : filter' p xs | otherwise = filter' p xs
```

Secondly, use `:{ ... :}` and indentation.

```
:{
let filter' _ [] = []
    filter' p (x:xs)
      | p x = x : filter' p xs
      | otherwise = filter' p xs
:}
```

(I've omitted the prompts to allow easier copy-pasting.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the
[Hammar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12484990/1060693),
you may set "allow multiline commands":

```
Prelude> :set +m
```

You may write your multiline definitions without `:{` and `:}` after that.
One empty line will finishing a block

```
Prelude> let filter' p (x:xs)
Prelude|      | p x       = x : filter' p xs
Prelude|      | otherwise = filter' p xs
Prelude|     filter' _ [] = []
Prelude|
Prelude>
```

If you want to switch back to a single-line mode, then you run `unset`:

```
Prelude> :unset +m
```